# IOS Get User current country reliably

Tags: ios, core-location

In my iOS App, I need to obtain the user current country.

I know that I can use `CLLocation` to retrieve the location and then `reverseGeocodeLocation` to get the country, but it will not work if the user doesn't authorize my app to get his location. 
I could maybe use `(Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode)`;
but I wonder if the countryCode change when the user travels or only when he manually change his settings?

Is it possible to retrieve this information from the current carrier operator ?

Comment: Then why don't you show the user popup to allow location if they reject again?

Comment: CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *object =  [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc]init];
  CTCarrier *carrierObject =  object.subscriberCellularProvider;
    carrierObject.isoCountryCode;   you can find the country code from CTCarrier. Now you have to convert this country code into country name. Note you are not using here location service. Country code is getting from carrier.

Comment: @elk_cloner It's not possible. on iOS, if the user reject the location authorization request; he has to manually toggle it on in the preferences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the country code using carrier by using this

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
```

Comment: Note that this will return a "wrong" answer anywhere near a border where you can connect accidentally to another countries mobile towers. This could happen quite regularly in Europe for instance.

Comment: This does not work from iOS 16.4.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the country without asking for location permissions using the following approach:

```
import MapKit

class CountryDectectorViewController: UIViewController {
    var didDetectCountryCode: ((String?) -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Map view setup
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        mapView.layoutIfNeeded()
        // Reverse geocoding map region center
        let location = CLLocation(
            latitude: mapView.region.center.latitude,
            longitude: mapView.region.center.longitude
        )
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, _ in
            self.didDetectCountryCode?(placemarks?.first?.isoCountryCode)
        }
    }
}
```

To ISO Country Code can be then obtained using:

```
let controller = CountryDectectorViewController()
controller.loadViewIfNeeded()
controller.didDetectCountryCode = { countryCode in
    print(countryCode)
}
```

**Some context**

I realised that UIKit has this information already because everytime the `MKMapView` is shown, the region is automatically set to fit the current user's country. Using this hypothesis I needed to find a solution to load the map without presenting it and then to reverse geocode the center coordinates to identify the country.

I implemented this solution taking into consideration the following limitations I found:

- Don't ask for user permissions ideally
- Device locale was not considered a reliable alternative
- Detecting the sim carrier actually returns the original carrier country and not the current connected carrier (via roaming)
- Retrieving the country by IP can be easily faked using VPNs which are becoming more popular lately